# Android ORMLite get expression expected error

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm reading OrmLite document and I'm try to create `DatabaseHelper` extends from `OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper`. After importing the library and creating the class, I get `expression expected error` for `ConnectionSource` in this code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase,
                     ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
    try{
        TableUtils.createTable(ConnectionSource, Categories.class);
    }catch (SQLException e){

    }
}
```

What is this problem and how to resolve that? My full created class is:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {

    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "eitaa_database.db";
    private static final String DATABASE_VERSION = "1";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION, R.raw.ormlite_config);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase,
                         ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        try{
            TableUtils.createTable(ConnectionSource, Categories.class);
        }catch (SQLException e){

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase,
                          ConnectionSource connectionSource,
                          int old_version, int new_version) {
        try{
            TableUtils.dropTable(ConnectionSource, Categories.class);
        }catch (SQLException e){

        }
    }
}
```

and my `Categories.java` class is:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "table_category")
public class Categories {

    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    public int id;

    @DatabaseField
    public String subject;

    public Categories() {
    }

    public Categories(int id, String subject, String text, Date date) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Categories{" +
                "  id=" + id +
                ", subject='" + subject + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line do you get the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this line: `TableUtils.createTable(ConnectionSource, Categories.class);` you have to use the variable name. Not the classname:

```
 TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, Categories.class);
```

See the lowercase `c`.